# Empty MySQL database and import from bash script?

Tags: mysql, mamp

Im trying to empty a database and import into it from a bash script. Im using MySQL from Mamp Pro. The following logs me into MySQL but doenst run any of the operations.

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p 
DROP DATABASE database_name;
CREATE DATABASE database_namem;
database_name < /file-to-import.sql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're suppose to execute the query as a string like this:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -pYourPassword -e "DROP DATABASE database_name;"
```

It might be possible to execute multiple queries this way by separating with `;` but I have not tried.

Comment: Out of interest what does the -e do? I cant find the answer from googeling it.

Comment: when i typed `mysql --help` it tells me `-e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history file.)`